# Visual Studio keeps referring to old files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

for my project where I'm working on, I've run into the problem where Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 seems to keep referring to old files, even when these have been excluded from the solution and new ones have been imported.

The situation in a whole:
I had a project where I've created a slightly different version of a specific class (a SIFT feature extractor, in case people are curious) which is a little bit more optimised and also fixed a bug or 2 that were in the code I found on the web. The result was me creating the following new files:

- SIFT.h - My version of the header for the feature extractor class
- SIFT.cpp - My implementation of the feature extractor class
- Keypoint.h - A header that defines the 'Keypoint' object, which is used by the feature extractor.
- Descriptor.h - A header that defines the 'Descriptor' object, which is the description of a Keypoint object.

These files added to a solution, which was built on OpenCV 2.2 version (which is a Computer Vision library), and this has the right linking to the libraries of the OpenCV 2.2 version. Compiled, ran it, works.

I had to change back to OpenCV 2.1 because of video support, which isn't working properly in 2.2 (or at least, I'm having problems with that version). For this I made a new solution, and linked everything to libraries of OpenCV 2.1. The files I mentioned above, I 'imported' them by right click corresponding folder -> Add -> Existing Item. So I imported the SIFT.cpp into the Source Files folder, and the 3 headers into the Header Files folder. Compiled, ran it, works.

Now comes the part where my problem occurs. A colleague of mine asked me to see what actually happens when I use the code I based mine on (that had the bugs in it and was slightly less optimised). So I removed the files I 'imported' with the 'Add-> Existing Item' method above, and then imported the other files also with the 'Add -> Existing Item' method. The files added are:
 - SIFT.h - The original version of the header for the feature extractor class
 - SIFT.cpp - The original implementation of the feature extractor class
 - KeyPoint.h - A header that defines the 'Keypoint' object, which is used by the feature extractor.
 - Descriptor.h - A header that defines the 'Descriptor' object, which is the description of a Keypoint object.
Note that there files indeed have almost the exact same names, but still have different content. I fixed a few interfacing errors because if different capitalization, then compiled it... And got these:

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
C:\Users\my name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\name solution\Release\name solution.exe

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SIFT::doSift(void)" (?doSift@SIFT@@QAEXXZ)
C:\Users\my name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\name solution\name solution\Executables.obj

I then noticed that the program is referring to the "doSift" method of the SIFT class, which is the naming of *my version* of SIFT, and not the other version I got from the internet which uses the name "DoSift" instead! I then started to check referencing in the code that uses the SIFT object (right click -> Go to Definition) and it refers to *my version* of SIFT.cpp instead of the other one that is now added to the solution (and is the only one in the solution.) The same applies to the headers... Visual Studio is referencing my versions that are not longer even in the solution, instead of the ones it should check which are in the solution.

I probably can work around this issue, by just creating a new solution from scratch. But that also means I have to set up the linking to the OpenCV files... And surely there is a way to prevent this additional work each and every time I would like to use a different version of the code.

I've already tried cleaning the solution (using the Clean Solution from the right click menu) and rebuilding after that. But that doesn't solve the issue. I'm not using any type of version control what-so-ever, because frankly... I don't understand these yet.

Anyone able to help me out with this one?
Thanks in advance,
Xilconic

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole 'Debug' and 'Release' directories? (and also moved those excluded files somewhere else)?

Comment: Are you certain your SIFT.h and SIFT.cpp are in the same directory? When you `#include "header.h"`, it will get the header out of the same directory as the .cpp file, regardless of what .h file you have included in your project.

Comment: @Yossarian I have indeed done this too manually, but to luck there.

Comment: @ Mark H The SIFT.h and the SIFT.cpp are indeed in the same directory, and in the project directory. Double clicking them in the Solution explorer opens the one in the project folder (internet version; is correct). Right clicking on the '#include SIFT.h' line -> Open Document 'SIFT.h', opens *my version* (not correct, not in project folder but somewhere else). Commenting this line and doing another #include SIFT.h, the compiler suggests in the auto compete *my version* again, and not using that auto complete still uses that one instead of the SIFT.h in project folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might check.  First, make sure you are not referencing any extra include directories (check the project ==> properties ==> c/c++ ==> general ==> "additional include directories" setting).  Second, I've found it helpful to actually open the vcproj file directly to see where the files are being pulled from.

Comment: The project had additional files that have to be presented (OpenCV related files, using VC++ Directories and Linker->Additional Dependencies) to the project, but here is no problem.
Looking at the project files XML, I can see the following:
Includes the Descriptor.h, KeyPoint.h, SIFT.h from the currect location, uses a Tutorial.h from *my version*. I haven't mentioned this header before, as I use it for linking to other methods, some of which use the SIFT.cpp. The included compile items are function from *my version*, and the SIFT.cpp fromt he correct location. No strange things here I guess.